# One PhpMyAdmin per virtualhost

Tags: mysql, php5, phpmyadmin, raspbian

I am relative new and learning about linux servers. I just played with them years ago.

I have configured `Apache2`, `Php5`, `MySQL`, `PhpMyAdmin`, etc. on a `Raspberry` using `Raspbian` (`Debian` dist).

I just configured some virtualhost where I am going to work, and now ***I want to know if I could configure each virtualhost to have their specific phpmyadmin access and databases***.

I googled for hours but I have found nothing.

Thank you! :)

Comment: hi, i think it should be possible, you can put a phpmyadmin in each "folder" you want, and just configure it from there calling the config page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this question in more than 1 stackexchange site because in 2 sites people told that was the wrong site, and I forgot this one. But the same question is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364378/one-phpmyadmin-per-virtualhost). **Below is a copy of the accepted answer**:

---

phpMyAdmin is available to every host via alias on addres [mysite.com/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin), and if u add databases and users, then restrict users to view only certain databases, when they login, they will see only one database.
And if u want to allow phpmyadmin for certain websites remove this line

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

from

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf
```

and add this to vhost of site you want to enable it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName onlyphpmyadmin.domain.com
    .
    .
    .
    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a private DNS server as you used raspberry to access DNS, setting your raspberry IP address to resolve domains. After apache, set the ServerName directive to phpmyadmin.xx.com and ServerAlias www.phpmyadmin.xx.com. When you create a DNS server using Bind9, you can use any name because it is private and then solves only if you have your ip configured as DNS on the client computer. You could do the same thing by using a server and buying a domain.
Post Apache2 Configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerName phpmyadmin.xxx.com
     ServerAlias www.phpmyadmin.xxx.com
     ServerSignature Off
     LogLevel warn
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
     DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
     # Secure your directory
     <Location />
        Options -Indexes
     </Location>
     # End Secure
     <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
          Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All # Enable .htaccess
          DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php # Set file default
          Order allow,deny # Access Directory
          Allow from all # Access All 
          # or access you ip
          Allow from <you private/public ip>
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Uhm. I do not want a DNS, because I am accessing through Internet. I am the domains owner.

Comment: Ok, I have posted the configuration of apache2 is valid even if you do not want to use a subdomain, just remove ServerName and ServerAlias

Comment: Hey @Riccardo, sorry for a late response, but I forgot this question and I have found another solution: I am posting it as answer